# Making Progress Bar to Draw over other apps

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-progressbar, countdowntimer

Hi i'm a beginner in android app development.

I need help making my app. so my app is a simple Timer with progress bar which works fine.
Now i need to make that "progress bar's" to draw over other apps even if the app is minimized or closed until the timer expires.

So for this I tried many things in many ways like i used Window Manager and other things in a service class, i even separated progress bar into different layout.

help me with code. the following contains code which works fine within app.

*1)Main Activity.java*

```
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateInterpolator;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


    private long timeCountInMilliSeconds = 1 * 60000;

    private enum TimerStatus {
        STARTED,
        STOPPED
    }

    private TimerStatus timerStatus = TimerStatus.STOPPED;

    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private ProgressBar progressBar1;
    private EditText editTextMinute;
    private TextView textViewTime;
    private ImageView imageViewReset;
    private ImageView imageViewStartStop;
    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    private ObjectAnimator smoothAnimation;
    private ObjectAnimator smoothAnimation1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // method call to initialize the views
        initViews();
        // method call to initialize the listeners
        initListeners();


    }

    /**
     * method to initialize the views
     */
    private void initViews() {
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        progressBar1 = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar1);
        editTextMinute = findViewById(R.id.editTextMinute);
        textViewTime = findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
        imageViewReset = findViewById(R.id.imageViewReset);
        imageViewStartStop = findViewById(R.id.imageViewStartStop);
    }

    /**
     * method to initialize the click listeners
     */
    private void initListeners() {
        imageViewReset.setOnClickListener(this);
        imageViewStartStop.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    /**
     * implemented method to listen clicks
     *
     * @param view
     */
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.imageViewReset:
                reset();
                break;
            case R.id.imageViewStartStop:
                startStop();
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * method to reset count down timer
     */
    private void reset() {
        stopCountDownTimer();
        startCountDownTimer();
    }


    /**
     * method to start and stop count down timer
     */
    private void startStop() {
        if (timerStatus == TimerStatus.STOPPED) {

            // call to initialize the timer values
            setTimerValues();
            // call to initialize the progress bar values
            setProgressBarValues();
            // showing the reset icon
            imageViewReset.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // changing play icon to stop icon
            imageViewStartStop.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_stop);
            // making edit text not editable
            editTextMinute.setEnabled(false);
            // changing the timer status to started
            timerStatus = TimerStatus.STARTED;
            // call to start the count down timer
            startCountDownTimer();

        } else {

            // hiding the reset icon
            imageViewReset.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            // changing stop icon to start icon
            imageViewStartStop.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_start);
            // making edit text editable
            editTextMinute.setEnabled(true);
            // changing the timer status to stopped
            timerStatus = TimerStatus.STOPPED;
            stopCountDownTimer();

        }

    }

    /**
     * method to initialize the values for count down timer
     */
    private void setTimerValues() {
        int time = 0;
        if (!editTextMinute.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            // fetching value from edit text and type cast to integer
            time = Integer.parseInt(editTextMinute.getText().toString().trim());
        } else {
            // toast message to fill edit text
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.message_minutes), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        // assigning values after converting to milliseconds
        timeCountInMilliSeconds = time * 1000;
    }

    /**
     * method to start count down timer
     */
    private void startCountDownTimer() {

        //left side Progress Bar
        smoothAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressBar, "progress", progressBar.getProgress(), progressBar.getMax());
        smoothAnimation.setDuration(5);
        smoothAnimation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());

        //right side Progress Bar
        smoothAnimation1 = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressBar, "progress", progressBar1.getProgress(), progressBar1.getMax());
        smoothAnimation1.setDuration(5);
        smoothAnimation1.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());

        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timeCountInMilliSeconds, 10) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                Log.d("TAG", "ON Tick Called "+millisUntilFinished);
                textViewTime.setText(hmsTimeFormatter(millisUntilFinished+1000));
                progressBar.setProgress((int) (timeCountInMilliSeconds / 10 - millisUntilFinished / 10));
                progressBar1.setProgress((int) (timeCountInMilliSeconds / 10 - millisUntilFinished / 10));

            }


            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

                textViewTime.setText(hmsTimeFormatter(timeCountInMilliSeconds));
                // call to initialize the progress bar values
                setProgressBarValues();
                // hiding the reset icon
                imageViewReset.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                // changing stop icon to start icon
                imageViewStartStop.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_start);
                // making edit text editable
                editTextMinute.setEnabled(true);
                // changing the timer status to stopped
                timerStatus = TimerStatus.STOPPED;
                smoothAnimation.end();
            }

        }.start();
        smoothAnimation.start();
        countDownTimer.start();
    }

    /**
     * method to stop count down timer
     */
    private void stopCountDownTimer() {
        countDownTimer.cancel();
    }

    /**
     * method to set circular progress bar values
     */
    private void setProgressBarValues() {

        progressBar.setMax((int) (timeCountInMilliSeconds / 10));
        progressBar.setProgress((int) (timeCountInMilliSeconds / 10));

        progressBar1.setMax((int) (timeCountInMilliSeconds / 10));
        progressBar1.setProgress((int) (timeCountInMilliSeconds / 10));

    }

    /**
     * method to convert millisecond to time format
     *
     * @param milliSeconds
     * @return HH:mm:ss time formatted string
     */
    private String hmsTimeFormatter(long milliSeconds) {

        String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(milliSeconds),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milliSeconds) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(milliSeconds)),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(milliSeconds) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milliSeconds)));

        return hms;


    }


}
```

*2)activity.xml*

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground">



    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:animationResolution="6000"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="14dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="0"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar_vertical" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar1"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="14dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:animationResolution="6000"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="0"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar_vertical" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextMinute"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textViewTime"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/hint_minute"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="15"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:minEms="5"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/colorYellow"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorYellow" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="00:01:00"
        android:textColor="@color/colorYellow"
        android:textSize="40sp" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewStartStop"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTime"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_start" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewReset"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewStartStop"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_reset"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        android:visibility="gone" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

The following contains some screenshots please take a look.

[Timer pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMSHE.png)
[Timer pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARKyf.png)

**The Above code works**

Now i added service code that i am **trying**
*-ProgressBarService.java* (In this i don't know which code should i move from main activity to this and HOW??)

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import static android.view.Gravity.END;

public class ProgressBarService extends Service {

    private WindowManager mWindowManager;
    private View mProgressView;


    public ProgressBarService() {
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mProgressView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.progressbar_view, null);

        final WindowManager.LayoutParams paramsProgress = getLayoutParams();
        paramsProgress.gravity=END;


        mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        if (mWindowManager != null) {
            mWindowManager.addView(mProgressView, paramsProgress);
        }
    }


    private WindowManager.LayoutParams getLayoutParams() {
        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        return params;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mProgressView != null) mWindowManager.removeView(mProgressView);
    }
}
```

*-progressbar_view* (seperated from activity_main)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:animationResolution="6000"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="14dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="100"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar_vertical" />

   <!-- <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar1"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="14dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:animationResolution="6000"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="100"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar_vertical" />-->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you also post the service code that you used?

Comment: Are you declaring permission android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW in your manifest and then requiring it in your app?

Comment: Continue time of progressbar in onpause and onresume functions

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58163135/is-there-any-way-to-show-progressbar-from-my-app-above-youtube-when-user-taps-my/58164472#58164472)

Comment: ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759279/how-to-bring-view-on-front-of-everything

Comment: @AbdullahRiaz yeah i have declared it.

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin so this is done in activity, but what about service?

Comment: @ShubhamGoel currently i'm having trouble with that. The code i have mentioned works fine as shown in screenshots.